# How to append some parameters to request and response in wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

I dont know how to append parameters like headers or cookies to the request and send it to the designated path in wiremock

Comment: Have you tried applications like Postman or Insomnia for sending http requests?

Comment: Yeah i have tried Postman.I am asking whether making changes to the original request dynamically is possible in wiremock as like ResponseDefinitionTransformer or ResponseTransformer for responses in wiremock.

Comment: Have you tried the regular expression request matching option: `urlMatching("/your/([a-z]*)\\?and=query")` that is described in the [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/)

Comment: With that i will not be able to make changes to the request right.

Comment: WireMock receives requests and has no out-of-the-box support for sending requests from WireMock to another application. This requires a custom module.

Comment: Can you say me about the custom module..

Answer (score 1):

In WireMock there is not out-of-the-box support for sending outbound requests to another application. This requires custom development as described in the [Extending WireMock](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/) section of the WireMock documentation.

When [searching on GitHub for WireMock](https://github.com/search?q=wiremock) there are quite a few projects that implement a Wiremock Extension. One project that might interest you is [wiremock-http-requests-maker](https://github.com/viniciusffj/wiremock-http-requests-maker) that allows for sending a single HTTP request.

If this doesn't suit your needs entirely, then it might serve as a good basis for your own development.